# Using MSSQL ROW_NUMBER() (or any window function) in D7 dynamic query with addExpression()

Tags: 7

I have a query with a bunch of joins, conditions, etc that uses `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)` to group the results so that I can filter them further on the resulting row number:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    X.id,
    Y.whatever,
    Z.blah,
    ...,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY X.id ORDER BY Y.whatever) roWNum
  FROM
    X JOIN Y ON ... JOIN Z ON ...
) Q
WHERE Q.rowNum = 1
```

This works perfectly in T-SQL, but when I try to implement it with a Drupal 7 dynamic query, it's no good. I do the following:

```
$query = db_select('Table1', 'X')->condition(...);
$query->innerJoin('Table2', 'Y', ...); 
$query->innerJoin('Table3', 'Z', ...);
$query->addField('X', 'id', 'myID');
$query->addField('Y', 'whatever', 'foo');
...
$query->addExpression('ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY X.id ORDER BY Y.whatever)', 'rowNum');

$outerQuery =
db_select($query, 'Q')
->fields('Q', array('rowNum', ...))
->condition('Q.rowNum', 1);
```

Drupal changes it to THIS in the actual query, which I print to the screen using `dpq()`:

```
SELECT
  Q.id, ..., cross_rowNum.cross_sqlsrv AS rowNum 
FROM (
  SELECT
    X.id,
    Y.whatever,
    Z.blah
  FROM
    X JOIN Y ON ... JOIN Z ON ...
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY X.id ORDER BY Y.whatever) cross_sqlsrv) cross_rowNum
) Q
WHERE rowNum = 1
```

which of course is totally useless to me, because `SELECT ROW_NUMBER()` by itself, without the FROM clause, always just returns 1!

Is there a way I can force Drupal to do what I want, i.e. select the `ROW_NUMBER()` from the tables specified in my FROM clause, instead of creating its own useless SELECT out of nothing - or should I forget about using a dynamic query and just hardcode the entire thing with `db_query()`?!

Comment: I'm confused - your code doesn't contain a `FROM` anywhere - where are you expecting that to come from? Drupal, or more accurately the module you're using for MSSQL integration, isn't likely to try to fill in parts of the query for you

Comment: @Clive I added more info - hope it's clear now.

Comment: Oh ok that makes more sense - it sounds like you've hit a limitation/bug in the sqlsrv module. If you look at the `replaceExpressionAliases()` method in the `SelectQuery_sqlsrv` class, you'll see this comment: _This function needs some work...._ That's the function which the `__toString()` method is using to operate on the expressions you've added.

Comment: @Clive Ah, I see... So it looks like there is no way to implement this using a dynamic select? I was really hoping to avoid using db_query()...

Comment: There might be a way to get around it but I'm afraid I don't know of one - personally I'd be grudgingly going back to `db_query` too